# How get the calling activity of an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have 2 list views :
  - The first one is instantiated in a fragment
  - The second one in a activity.
  They display the same information

On click on a list item, I open another activity to display item detail.

Depending on the calling activity/fragment, I want to render a different layout, so I need to know in the activity that render the detail of a item, which activity created the intent ?

getCallingActivity and getParentActivityIntent seems to be declarative and fixe, isn"t it ? in my case there are both null.

How can I do that ?

Comment: maybe pass a value via putExtra getExtra intent methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an argument with your intent as:

```
intent.putExtra("ParentActivity", "ActivityA");
```

or

```
intent.putExtra("ParentActivity", "ActivityB");
```

In your next activity, use this:

```
String parentActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("ParentActivity");
```

And render the layout according to result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I could imagine we can do that, but is there not a more official way for doing this than putting a customized extra in the intent ?

Comment: No. As far as I know. @Anthony will let you know if find. :)

Comment: Besides, `getCallingActivity()` method will only work when you have started the child activity as a `startActivityForResult`